# JSP file opening like a download file

Tags: java, jsp

I've created a web project on netbeans and my time.jsp page is open like a download file instead open the page on Internet Explorer.
Why is it happening? 
Thanks.

```
<jsp version="2.1" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/page"
      xmlns:webuijsf="http://www.sun.com/webui/webuijsf">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html:charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>
<f:view>
    <webuijsf:page id="page1">
      <webuijsf:html id="html1">
        <webuijsf:head id="head1" title="Web Time: A Simple Example">
          <webuijsf:link id="link1" url="/resources/stylesheet.css"/> 
          <webuijsf:meta content="60" httpEquiv="refresh"/>
        </webuijsf:head>  
          <webuijsf:body id="body1" style="-rave-layout: grid">
              <webuijsf:form id="form1">
                  <webuijsf:staticText id="timeHeader"
                                       style="font-size: 18px; left: 24px; top: 24px;
                                       position: absolute"
                                       text="Current time on the web server"/>
                  <webuijsf:staticText binding=""
                                       id="clockText" style="background-color: black;
                                       color: yellow; font-size: 18px; left: 24px;
                                       top: 48px; position: absolute"/>
                </webuijsf:form>
          </webuijsf:body>                
          </webuijsf:html>   
        </webuijsf:page> 
</f:view>
```

Comment: please share your code maybe it will help to understand the problem

Comment: added my code! Thank you

Comment: Did you verify your content-type in the response header ? what it says

Comment: I just did and it worked! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are most likely not running it on a server that knows how to handle jsp, so it will just pass the file to the browser. The browser also don't know how to handle it, so it'll simply be downloaded.
You need a web container like tomcat running on your server.

[This guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/run-your-first-jsp-program-in-apache-tomcat-server) will tell you what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks Mate! But a can run another JSP page! Just that one a cannot.

Comment: Then you have to provide some code and more information about how and where you are running it.